# Color change using onclick.getElementById().style.color only works in Firefox?

Tags: jquery, select, colors, html-table, onclick

I have a table where I would like to change the text color of the TH row using the following code:

```
<select>
  <option onclick="document.getElementById('tablehead').style.color=''">Default</option>
  <option onclick="document.getElementById('tablehead').style.color='red'">Red</option>
  <option onclick="document.getElementById('tablehead').style.color='yellow'">Yellow</option>
  <option onclick="document.getElementById('tablehead').style.color='green'">Green</option>
</select>
```

This works perfectly as it should in Firefox, but when I test it in any other browser, it wont work. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using native javascript

```
<select onchange="document.getElementById('tablehead').style.color=this.value">
  <option value=''>Default</option>
  <option value='red'>Red</option>
  <option value='yellow'>Yellow</option>
  <option value='green'>Green</option>
</select>
<div id="tablehead">tablehead</div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r4fP9/)

Comment: While all of you posted in-depth and good answers, I went with this since im new to js/jQuery and it made the most sense to me :) Anyways, It works now! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery you can listen to change event:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
   $('#tablehead').css('color', this.value.toLowerCase());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should watch the `onChange` event of your `select` instead, this requires to add a `value` to your `options`. You cannot rely on that the user selects a value by clicking the option and as you see, not all browsers fire the click event.

Pseudo code:

```
<select onChange="if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == 1) { red } else if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == 2) { green }">
```